# how to make this code short for both events

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I have the following code. how can I make it short so it work with click and enter so I dont have to duplicate it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
       $('form#myform').submit();
     }
   });

   $('#mybutton').click(function() {
     $('form#myform').submit();
   });  

});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this would be a shorter one, it takes advantage of the event bubbling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(this).on('keypress click', function(e) {
       if(e.which == 13 || e.target.id==='mybutton')
           $('form#myform').submit();
   });  
});​
```

this is how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/e6L3W/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

(Although use of `$(this)` on document ready is not clear or might be its a typo and it supposed to be a input box.)

Hope this helps the cause and also read the link below: `:)`

[Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery)

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#search').keypress(function(event) { //<<== #search is input box id
     if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        $('#mybutton').trigger('click');
     }
   })

   $('#mybutton').click(function() {
     $('form#myform').submit();
   });  

});​
```

**OR**

```
      var myFunction = function() {
        $('form#myform').submit();
      }

     $('#search').keypress(function(event) { //<<== #search is input box id
         if ( event.which == 13 ) {
            myFunction;
         }
       })

       $('#mybutton').click(myFunction);
```

**OR**

You could try chaining like this:

This will bind `#element` to the events but might be you are looking to bind 2 separate elements with 2 separate event but same outcome.

```
$('#element').bind('keypress click', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(this).bind('keypress click', function(e) {
       if(e.type == 'click') {
           if(e.target.id == 'mybutton') {
             $('form#myform').submit();
           }
       } else if(e.type == 'keypress') {
           if(e.which == 13) {
             $('form#myform').submit();
           }
       }
   });
});​
```